# Звуки, обозначаемые буквой "я", в предударных слогах

Tags: фонетика

Какой (какие) из перечисленных звуков может обозначать буква «я» в предударных
слогах общеупотребительных знаменательных слов? (Если можно, с примерами.)

1. [й’а];
2. [а];
3. [й’и];
4. [и].

Comment: Я думаю, что 4. Например в слове *автотягач* (если рассматривать только предложенные варианты, то там звук [и] обозначается буквой *я*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Теоретически - все четыре. Тут вопрос, во-первых, какие слова считать "общеупотребительными знаменательными", во-вторых, традиций какой школы придерживается автор вопроса.

**[й’а] - бильярдист**. Вопреки общим правилам в этом слове пока проговаривается почти чистое [йa].
**[а] - глясе (кофе-глясе)** Иноязычное слово в процессе "обкатки" языком пока сохраняет качество языка-источника.
Эти два варианта - единичные случаи, их можно оспорить.

**[й’и] - японец, пояснение**. Звук средний между [й'и] и [й'э], но обычно транскрибируется первым вариантом.
**[и] - тяжёлый, пятёрка**

Comment: Олимпиада "Ломоносов", следовательно, Московской, наверно. Спасибо! Я вот в *бильярдист* произношу скорее что-то похожее на [и], нежели [йа], но это так, кстати.

Comment: Вы "биллиард" произносите или "бильярд"? Первое сейчас устаревает, а из второго просто невозможно получить чистое [и], разве только [йи].

Comment: Кажется, *бильярд*. Но в *бильярдист*, выходит, все смешалось. Хотя, может, я ошибаюсь, надо на аппаратуре смотреть.